# Is there any chance we can use specific Controller action based on a parameter (get parameter) in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, controllers

Basically, I want the following Route.

```
Route::get('/{parameter}', 'SomeController@parameter');
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in way, but it's quite trivial to implement yourself:

```php
class SomeController {

    public function route($method)
    {
        if ( ! method_exists($this, $method))
        {
            app()->abort(404);
        }

        return $this->{$method}();
    }

}
```

Then in your routes:

```php
Route::get('/{parameter}', 'SomeController@route');
```

---

If you want to pass any additional parameters to their respective methods, use this:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SomeController {

    public function route($method, Request $request)
    {
        if ( ! method_exists($this, $method)) app()->abort(404);

        $parameters = array_slice($request->segments(), 1);

        return call_user_func_array([$this, $method], $parameters);
    }

}
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks...
Would you suggest doing this or better to stick with the standard Controller actions... ? @Joseph Silber

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed - It's really up to you, though [I personally wouldn't do it](https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil/).